# with POI API 3.17 XSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE cannot be resolved

Tags: apache-poi

I am new to POI. This is my piece of code:

```
XSSFHyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(XSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE);
```

In above code I am getting error:

```
-LINK_FILE  cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I am using POI-3.17:

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the `apache poi` [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#How+to+create+hyperlinks) is not up to date. The fields in [Hyperlink](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/Hyperlink.java?view=markup#l49) are removed in version 3.17.  Instead [CreationHelper.createHyperlink](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html#createHyperlink-org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType-) uses a enumeration [HyperlinkType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/HyperlinkType.html) to determine the type.

So

```
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.FILE);
```

would be correct now.

But the documentation in https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/ is **not** the API docu for the last stable version but for the current developer version. So you need to have a look at [the CreationHelper.java of your version](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.java?view=markup#l46) to confirm that the API docu is right for this version. In this case it is.